# System.Data.SQLite is not working in Mono

Tags: sqlite, monodevelop, system.data.sqlite

I have C#.Net project which contains the SQLite database uses. I need to convert this C#.Net project into MonoDevelop. SQLite is not working properly in mono. Please confirm Mono.Data.Sqlite is right assembly to resolve this problem. Is there any simple way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Did you try http://www.mono-project.com/SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

You can see an small example of SQlite + Monodevelop on: http://www.mono-tematico.com.ar/2013/04/monodevelop-sqlite.html#more

You can see: "INSERT INTO" & "SELECT *"

Best regards.